# Responsive Outlook Signature

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, outlook, signature

Hi is it possible to add a responsive signature to outlook.  I have my html doc which works as responsive in internet browser, but not on email.  Any ideas?

here is my code (which i have imported as html signature in outlook)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Signature</title>

<style>
    .mainImage{

    }
    .someText {
     background-color: blue;
                }

    @media only screen and (min-width:480px){
            .mainImage{
                       width: 50%;
                       float: left;
                                                }
     .someText {
                        width: 50%;
                        float: right;
                                                }
    }
</style>

</head>
<body >
<div class="mainImage">
                <IMG SRC="./MyApps/bouncy-cat-icon.png" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="auto" STYLE="BACKGROUND-COLOR:BLACK; max-width: 300px"/>
</div>
<div class="someText">
<P>TESITDFNGLEDG JLDBJLS GHSJETDJ</P>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help on this would be great (if it is even possible)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTML in Outlook is rendered by Word, not IE. It does a few things differently, and some HTML features are not supported at all.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office Outlook uses the HTML parsing and rendering engine from Microsoft Office Word to display HTML message bodies. The following series of articles describes limitations and possibilities, provides reference documentation related to supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)